# Does a union ruin indexing in MySQL 5.6?

Tags: mysql, sql

A question on how MySQL works under the hood.  Say I have two tables, table1, and table2_archive.  They are identical in columns and indexed columns.

If I try running queries that involve

```
(

 SELECT * FROM table1 
 UNION 
 SELECT * FROM table1

) as allTable1
```

in the middle of it, with where and join clauses on columns of the newly formed allTable1, are the indexes previously declared on table1/table1_archive now not helpful give they were turned into a new table?

Same qusetion for something like

```
SELECT IF table1.col1 IS NULL THEN table1_archive.col1 ELSE table1.col1.
```

I am using MySQL 5.6.

Comment: select * from  table1   .. don't use index  .. you are doing a full scan ..(you have not where  condition)

Comment: A derived table in general will generally prevent any indexes on the underlying tables.  Union just makes matters worse.

Comment: That's what I thought.  We do this at work a lot for somne projects and it drives me mad, My intuition was just having a single well indexed table would be much faster than having two tables, and then unioning them or doing if/else, especially since they are only a few million rows at max.  I just wanted to be sure before I brought it up with anyone about changing how we operate here.

Comment: A derived table based on union is most likely end up as a temporary table. Whether MySQL adds an index to the derived table, you can tell by looking at the explain. If you see a ref or eqref type join between the derived table and the other parts of the query, then MySQL did add an index. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/derived-table-optimization.html